# Why was Rose in "Beyond Skyline" a hybrid?

Tags: beyond-skyline

Just watched "[Beyond Skyline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_Skyline)" and was left scratching my head about a major plot point. The baby, Rose, is apparently an alien/human hybrid, resulting in

> her rapidly aging as well as having an innate understanding of the alien technology.

Unless I missed some dialogue, it was implied that she was a hybrid because her father Jarrod was altered by the alien technology. However, in the first movie, Elaine told Jarrod she was pregnant before the aliens ever invaded. And, unless I missed a major scene in the first one, Elaine was never experimented on by the aliens - there was just a scene near the end where the aliens were removing babies from pregnant women.

**So... how exactly is Rose a hybrid?**

Comment: That's the only thing about *Beyond Skyline* that left you scratching your head?

Comment: @Valorum - lol no, there were other things. But her being a hybrid was a big deal, and I don't think they ever tried to explain it. IIRC there was some throwaway line about the baby moving when she looked into the blue light, but that was it.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, in the first movie, the aliens took control of humans just by shining a blue light on them. So, by mentioning that the baby moved when the blue light was on Elaine, the movie tells us that the blue light affected the unborn baby.